# Wubi (32 bit ISO) freezes on "almost finished copying files"

Tags: 12.10, wubi, 32-bit, fat32

Basically what it says on the tin. After accidentally installing the 64 bit version, I uninstalled it and tried to install the 32 bit version, but the installation freezes. I've seen some answers saying that you have to change your format to FAT32, but to be honest I'm a complete newbie and don't know how to do that.

Comment: There's no benefit to switching to FAT32 - only negatives, like limited size of the virtual disks. I'd suggest you try again and if it freezes see if you can get to a terminal and capture the logs (Ctrl+Alt+F1) `sudo zip -r /host/ubuntu/install-logs.zip /var/log` and then attach them to a bug report (e.g. from `C:\ubuntu\install-logs.zip` when back in Windows). To exit the shell either Ctrl+Alt+F7 back to install GUI, or `sudo reboot`.